# How to solve unresolved reference fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin

So, for some reason in the fragment activity class  onCreate does not find the fragment_layouts.

```
 override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_employees, container, false)
}
```

The R.layout.fragment_employees is in red and it is not recognized. Why is that and how to solve it?

Comment: Just try building your application. The `R` class is automatically generated from XML, but not continuously; it only happens during the build.

Comment: I'd also suggest you make sure the R file imported belongs to your package and isn't accidentally imported from some other module.

Comment: @Thomas I tried to build, it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do is to File->Invalidate Caches/Restart and then it fixed itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at your imports. For some reason, I had the imported "import android.R"
and that was causing the error. I deleted it and this resolve the issue.